# If the user has no active records, read the inactive records using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
 id    userid    marks  status
  1      100      50      active
  2      100      55      inactive
  3      101      60      active
  4      102      70      inactive
```

I'm writing a single query to read users with the status "inactive." status only .

```
SELECT id, userid, marks
from user
where status = 'inactive'
```

Desired output is

```
   4      102      70      inactive

  Only the inactive records for this user.
```

Users are retried with active status also as per my query. if someone can assist me. I appreciate you.

Comment: 1) Subj contradicts the text. 2) What is desired output for shown data?

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking us for help with

Comment: Are you looking to add a `WHERE userid = 102` to your query?

Comment: One person can have multiple status in my table. There may be active and inactive entries for any user. I only want to view information about users who are inactive.i don't want records with both status together

Comment: Is `2      100      55      inactive`  an acceptable record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, userid, marks 
FROM user 
WHERE userid NOT IN (
  SELECT userid 
  FROM user 
  WHERE status = 'active'
  GROUP BY userid
)
```